# Find if user search is within a part of any array fields

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I'm trying to figure out a way to see if user entered search term relates to anything in the `$propertyData` array.

So far I have used `in_array()` function, but to my understanding it will only match if user entered search term matches array field exactly e.g. User entered "This is a house" and it matches first field in an array wich is "This is a house", but if user enters "This is a" or "a house" it will not match, even though these words are present in that field.

```
if(in_array($getSearch, $propertyData)) {
   // $getSearch is user input
   // $propertyData is array containing fields
}
```

Is there a function / way that can be used to achieve a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [preg_grep()](https://www.php.net/preg_grep).  It searches an array by regular expression and returns an array of values that matched the expression.  So if anything other than an empty array is returned it is considered true:

```
if(preg_grep("/$getSearch/", $propertyData)) {
```

For case insensitive add the `i` modifier:

```
if(preg_grep("/$getSearch/i", $propertyData)) {
```

If you want an array of all of the values that matched (if more than 1) also, then:

```
if($matches = preg_grep("/$getSearch/i", $propertyData)) {
```

Comment: Did the trick, could you please expand on what exactly happens here?

Comment: @Ilja: Added a little description.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) in conjunction with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) scan your array for partial matches of the search-string and return items where a match is found:

```
$result = array_filter($array, 
    function ($item) use ($getSearch) {
        return (strpos($item, $getSearch) !== FALSE);
    },
$propertyData);
```

Alternatively, you could use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) as suggested in AbraCadaver's answer. It returns an array consisting of the elements of the input array that match the given pattern. The regular expression needs to be enclosed in delimiters. I've used `/` below:

```
// escape search pattern to allow for special characters
$searchPattern = preg_quote($getSearch, '/');

if ($arr = preg_grep("/$searchPattern/", $propertyData)) {
    print_r($arr);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I assume `preg_grep()` being the fastest in wild-life solutions. +1 Maybe will once make a benchmark, to compare this.. However, now I see that nobody suggested a database so far .. If the data grows this might be the fastest attempt at the end..

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$found = FALSE;
foreach($propertyData as $property) {
    if(strpos($userQuery, $property)) {
        $found = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if `$propertyData` grows, this solution will get slow. Then you could use a database for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
foreach($propertyData as $data )
{
    if( strpos($data, $getSearch) )
    {
        //match found
    }
}
```